# Returning value of previous grouped record

Tags: sql, excel

My dataset looks like this

| ParentID | ChildID | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULl | 1/12/2021 | 100 |
| 1 | 1-1 | 2/12/2021 | 200 |
| 2 | NULL | 1/12/2021 | 500 |
| 2 | 2-1 | 2/12/2021 | 700 |
| 2 | 2-2 | 3/12/2021 | 900 |

I need to return the previous value grouped by the ParentID. I can achieve this quite easily using the LAG window function in SQL. I have attempted to use a mix of OFFSET and MATCH, however having difficulty.

**Expected output**

| ParentID | ChildID | Date | Value | PreviousValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | 1/12/2021 | 100 | NULL |
| 1 | 1-1 | 2/12/2021 | 200 | 100 |
| 2 | NULL | 1/12/2021 | 500 | NULL |
| 2 | 2-1 | 2/12/2021 | 700 | 500 |
| 2 | 2-2 | 3/12/2021 | 900 | 700 |

**The SQL translation for this would be**

`LAG(value,1) OVER (PARTITION BY ParentID ORDER BY Date ASC)`.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by previous record? What result do you expect from given data?

Comment: @Harun24HR - apologies have added in the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try on below formula-

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,A2)=1,"",INDEX(FILTER($D$2:$D$6,$A$2:$A$6=A2),COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,A2)))
```

[image]

Comment: this formula only seems to return the same value. Is it possible to use an alternative function to FILTER?